# Effects of continuing after a total party wipe?

Tags: dragon-age-inquisition

I've had a couple of encounters so far where I stumbled into enemies that were higher level than expected and gotten wiped out. At the game over screen, I chose the option "Continue". After doing so, I didn't notice any negative consequences. I was plopped back just a few metres from the area I died, and was free to continue on as if nothing had happened. Am I missing something? Is there some negative effect from a party wipe?

Comment: The continue thing just load the last save point (auto or manual save). I guess you're just lucky in the case you did not have to replay half an hour or something. Just give it a try next time it happens to you, press continue and go to the "load" menu, the last save should be the one which is loaded

Comment: If you habitually quicksave prior to combat, that's why it's always starting you off just a few meters away from where you died.

Comment: Thanks guys. I guess it was just the autosave that was being reloaded. It's only happened to me twice, and both times the game must have autosaved just seconds before the encounter. I've previously only ever saved in Haven after coming back from adventuring, but I'll make sure to save more in the future!

@Nitro.de: if you make your comment into an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I find that the game tends to autosave just before big battles.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The option "Continue" just means "load the lastest save". Dragon Age Inquisition uses the autosave function which is triggered if you get close to hard fights like bosses and at some random spots that i dont know. To answer your question - there're no negative consequences for loading your last savepoint and it seems that you just triggered an autosave just before your party wiped out. If you look in the menu under "load" you should at least find one autosave.